# Spring REST controller behaves differently in unit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

### The problem

I am new to Spring and trying to write some unit tests for my REST controller. Testing manually with `httpie` or `curl` works well, however, with `@WebMvcTest`, strange things happen.

Here is what happens when I `PUT` a new user by `curl`:

```
$ curl -v -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d@- localhost:8080/api/users <john_smith.json                                                                                                                                  
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /api/users HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 102
> 
* upload completely sent off: 102 out of 102 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sat, 18 Apr 2020 22:29:43 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"id":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","email":"john.smith@example.com","password":"l33tp4ss"}
```

As you can see, the Content-Type header is there in the response and the body is indeed the new `User`.

Below is how I am trying to test the same automatically:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService service;

    private final User john = new User("John", "Smith",
                                       "john.smith@example.com",
                                       "s3curep4ss");

    @Test
    public void givenNoUser_whenCreateUser_thenOk()
    throws Exception
    {
        given(service.create(john)).willReturn(john);

        mvc.perform(post("/users")
                    .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectToJsonBytes(john)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(0)))
        .andDo(document("user"));
    }

}
```

But what I get is this:

```
$ mvn test
[...]
MockHttpServletRequest:                                                                                                                
      HTTP Method = POST    
      Request URI = /users                   
       Parameters = {}                                                                                                                 
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"103"]                                                                                                                                                                                     
             Body = {"id":0,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","email":"john.smith@example.com","password":"s3curep4ss"}
    Session Attrs = {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

Handler:                
             Type = webshop.controller.UserController
           Method = webshop.controller.UserController#create(Base)                                                                     

Async:                                        
    Async started = false                                                                                                              
     Async result = null                      

Resolved Exception:                       
             Type = null                                           

ModelAndView:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        View name = null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
             View = null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            Model = null                                                                                                               

FlashMap:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
       Attributes = null                                           

MockHttpServletResponse:    
           Status = 200                      
    Error message = null                                                                                                               
          Headers = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     Content type = null                                                                                                               
             Body =                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    Forwarded URL = null                                                                                                               
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []                               
[ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.271 s <<< FAILURE! - in webshop.UserControllerTest          
[ERROR] givenNoUser_whenCreateUser_thenOk  Time elapsed: 0.376 s  <<< FAILURE!                                                         
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set
        at webshop.UserControllerTest.givenNoUser_whenCreateUser_thenOk(UserControllerTest.java:70)
```

**What is happening? Where is the body from the `MockHttpServletResponse`? I must be missing something, as it seems to act completely differently.**

---

### Other code in case it is needed

My generic controller class:

```
public class GenericController<T extends Base>
implements IGenericController<T> {

    @Autowired
    private IGenericService<T> service;

    @Override
    @PostMapping(consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                 produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public T create(@Valid @RequestBody T entity)
    {
        return service.create(entity);
    }

    /* ... Other RequestMethods ... */

}
```

The actual `User` controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/users")
public class UserController extends GenericController<User> { }
```

---

**UPDATE 2020-04-22**
As suggested, I took generics out of the equation, but it did not help.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, and is there a reason why you are not using the spring `MediaType` class?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf ah, thank you. The `_UTF8` version was reinventing the wheel then, and also unnecessary. I removed it altogether now. However, this seems to be irrelevant to my problem (I also updated my question with the right `MediaType`).

Comment: The uris show different: /api/users vs /users. Could that have something to do?

Comment: @Juan no, I think the test also runs in the context of `/api` and therefore I don’t need to specify that (I have set `server.servlet.contextPath=/api` in my `application.properties`).

Comment: Perhaps I should also mention that I have several other tests that run fine and I can see the body (and Content-Type header) of the response in the test log.

Comment: i have a suspicion but im not sure, that your mock is returning null. Mostly because you are saying that you want a specific object and java is pass by value so it wants THAT specific object and not any other. Your controller on the other hand passes a newly created object which is not that specific value. Could you please check and debug and see what `service.create(entity)` returns?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I am not sure what you mean, I tried adding `if (service.create(john) != null) System.out.println("ok");` and it indeed printed the `ok` during the test run, so the mock doesn’t return `null`. My controller returns what its `service` returns, which is being mocked and returns what I tell it to (`john`). At least as far as I understand.

Comment: can you please print what the mock is returning? or debug and set a debug point and look at what the mock is returning so i can see what it is you are trying to send back.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf The mock returns a `User` instance; eg `System.out.println(((User)service.create(john)).getEmail())` → `john.smith@example.com`

Comment: have you ever debugged your application?

Comment: I don’t understand how setting a breakpoint and checking the returned value there would be any different than simply dumping the object on the console. The returned `User` object has the same hash the same as the one defined in the test class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211980/discussion-between-thomas-andolf-and-bp99).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was with this line:

```
given(service.create(john)).willReturn(john);
```

When I change the first `john` (which is a `User` object) to e.g. `any()`, the test passes just fine.

---

Could somebody please shed some light for me as to why this is? Swapping `john` with `any()` works, but feels somewhat hacky. The controller passes the JSON deserialized `john` object to its service. Is it simply that that deserialized `john` is obviously not the same object as the one I create in the test class?

Comment: Have you definitely implemented `equals` on your `Ueer` class correctly?

Comment: Oh I didn’t realize I had to do that. You nailed it, now it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Yup, you'll need that. `equals()` is the method that you have to implement in order for Java to test whether objects are "meaningfully equal". Without it, Java has no idea whether two distinct objects should be considered the same or not - even if their state is identical. (You should also implement `hashcode()` as well for consistency.)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the `@WebMvcTest` annotation is configuring a `UserService` bean that is using the real implementation, and your bean is somehow ignored.

We can try to create the `UserService` bean differently

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@Import(UserControllerTest.Config.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {

        @Primary
        @Bean
        UserService mockedUserService() {
            UserService service = Mockito.mock(UserService.class);
            given(service.create(john)).willReturn(UserControllerTest.john());
            return service;
        }
    }

    static User john() {
        return new User("John", "Smith", "john.smith@example.com", "s3curep4ss");
    }

    ...
}
```

You could also move the stubbing to a `@Before` method in your tests

```java
@Configuration
public class CommonTestConfig {
   @Primary
   @Bean
   UserService mockedUserService() {
      return Mockito.mock(UserService.class)
   }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@Import(CommonTestConfig.class)
public class Test1 {
   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @Before
   public void setup() {
      given(userService.create(any())).willReturn(user1());
   }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@Import(CommonTestConfig.class)
public class Test2 {
   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @Before
   public void setup() {
      given(userService.create(any())).willReturn(user2());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but your answer does not seem to work. Do I understand correctly that I should remove `@MockBean private UserService service` from my `UserControllerTest` and instead have this `@TestConfiguration` block there? Also, it looks like you define what the mock does before the test cases (eg give `.create(john)`, return `john()`). Shouldn’t I be able to do this on a per-test basis? I mean in one test, I want to try what happens when there are no users. In another, I want to pretend there is a user and check if it is returned by a `GET` request.

Comment: No, you can also stub the mock in a `@Before` method. See my updated answer

Comment: When I do it like this, I get `Field repository in UserService required a bean of type 'IUserRepository' that could not be found.` I don’t understand, isn’t the point of mocking that I just create an object that looks and acts like a `UserService` but is not actually a `UserService` instance (and therefore does not need a `IUserRepository`)?

Comment: I found the problem! I see that you used `.create(any())` instead of putting a `User` object there, so I tried it this way and it works. Seems like the problem is with the line `given(service.create(john)).willReturn(john)`.